# PostgresSQL unable to read csv files on my desktop

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file into postgresSQL, however, I keep getting the error that no such file exists or directory.

this is the line of code I execute copy mu_data from

> copy mu_data from 'users/mysurname/Desktop/FILE.CSV' DELIMITER ',' CSV
>   HEADER;

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Are you missing the leading `/` on the path?

Comment: no, I have tried this as well it did not work

Answer (score 3):

`copy` is a command run on the server side. So unless your Postgres server happens to be on your localhost, the file very likely doesn't exist from the view of the server.

So one solution is you to transfer the file to the servers filesystem somehow. Or, if you're using the `psql` command line tool (or at least can use it for this task), you can use the [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) command there.

Comment: actually, you have a point, but I believe, my Postgres server is on my localhost. Not heard of psql

Comment: How would I take the file to the servers file system?

Comment: SFTP, FTP, USB stick, floppy disk (yes, I am *that* old)... That depends on what the machine offers you and is a *very* broad question.

Comment: I know, sorry! I just want it to read my bloody cvs file. seem like such a headache to get it too work

Comment: (If your server is on your local machine) The simplest solution is to move or copy your.csv file to /tmp/ , which is world-readable.

Comment: How do I do this?